# How to pass variable of text field of html to typescript in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form>
    <input id = "username" type="text" name="username" ngModel placeholder="username">
    <input id = "password" type="password" name="password" ngModel placeholder="password">
</form>
<button name="buttonLogin" type="button" (click)="login()" style="height:30px; width:100px;">Login</button>
```

Here is my component.ts file code:

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  username: any;
  password: any;

  login(){
    this.authService.login(this.username,this.password).subscribe(data=>console.log('login 
    successful'));//email pass will be fetched from text boxes
  }
}
```

I have tried many ways to get input from the text field into the component.ts file variables. but no method works. I am working on frontend as well as backend. This is the authorization part. If i pass `username` and `password` values directly in the component.ts file then the login is successful all the way to the backend and the database. But when I try to get variables of the input text fields in the html file then it doesn't work.
Please have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Hey there are two ways to make forms in angular :

1. Reactive forms

With this method, you have to define your properties like this :

```
export class AuthComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['default value', [/*Validators*/]]
      password: ['default value', [/*Validators*/]]
    })

  }

  login(){
    this.authService.login(this.myForm.value.username,this.myForm.value.password).subscribe(data=>console.log('login 
    successful'));//email pass will be fetched from text boxes
  }
}
```

and then you can use it as below :

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input id = "username" formGroupName="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
    <input id = "password" formGroupName="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
</form>
<button name="buttonLogin" type="button" (click)="login()" style="height:30px; width:100px;">Login</button>
```

2. Template-driven forms

With this method, you have to bind your input thanks to the `[(ngModel)]` property :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"
       required
       [(ngModel)]="username" name="username">
```

If needed, you can check the doc about forms in angular :)

Reactive form : https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Template driven form : https://angular.io/guide/forms

PS : The click event on the submit button is working but the correct way to build a form is to set a (submit) event on the form and a button with type="submit" :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Two way binding to get the values for username, password.

```
 <form>
          <input id = "username" type="text" name="username" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="username">
          <input id = "password" type="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="password">
 </form>
```

Also refer to Angular forms documentation to find more information and types of forms.
https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview